# How to combine the column values from the same table with condition in sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to combine the Currency field by comparing **Config** and **Product** Column. If both field is repeated with duplicate values but different currency, the combine the currency into single row as you see in the screenshot.

I tried the code like

```
Select  DISTINCT LC.Config, LC.Product, CONCAT(LC.Currency,',',RC.Currency) as Currencies FROM [t_LimitCurrency] LC INNER JOIN [t_LimitCurrency] RC ON LC.[Config] = RC.[Config] AND LC.Product = RC.Product
```

[image]

Please let me know, how to write select statement for this scenario.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to supply sample data and expected results, please do so as DDL and DML statements and markdown tables respectively.

Comment: Please provide the actual SQL you have attempted so we may best assist you here

Comment: Added my code. But it is not workout for me

Comment: This is a SQL Anti-Pattern. SQL is specifically designed for the multi-row format you're starting with. If you're going to use this data in further SQL, do ***not*** do this. If you're doing this for presentation purposes, don't do this in your data layer, do it in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Code should do the trick. I am using `XML Path` but you can use `String_AGG` in latest version of `sql server`

```
   select distinct Config,Product,
   STUFF((SELECT  ' ,' + CAST(Currency AS VARCHAR(max)) [text()]
   FROM (
   SELECT Currency
   FROM Yourtable b
  
   WHERE a.Config=b.Config and a.product=b.product
   ) ap
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
  .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Currency
   from Yourtable a
```

EDIT 1 : for latest version of `sql server` code should be like below

```
select distinct Config,Product,
(SELECT 
STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Currency), ',')
FROM YourTable b WHERE a.Config=b.Config and a.product=b.product) 
Currency
from Yourtable a
```

Comment: To improve your answer, you could add the query using String_AGG. I think it would be better to show this option as prefered query instead of the older approach for obsolete versions.

Comment: XML PATH('') itself working perfectly. So, I just followed it. Not using String_AGG. Thanks!!

Comment: No one said it doesn't work. The point is that on new SQL Server DB's, STRING_AGG is the best option for that.